# LINQ: how to get 1 month records

Tags: c#, .net, linq

The following query is returning a number of daily orders. I want to create another query that will return **int** number of **orders in one month**. The problem is some months have 29days, some 30 or 31. Any help is appreciated!

```
public int GetNewDailyOrders()
{
    return _DbContext.Carts.Where(x => x.Created >= DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1)).Count();
}
```

Comment: `Where(x => x.Created.Month == 12`?

Comment: I think I got it:             return _DbContext.Carts.Where(x => x.Created.Month >= DateTime.UtcNow.Month).Count(); but I'm not completly sure it's the right solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public int GetMonthlyOrders(int month, int year)
{

    return _DbContext.Carts.Count(x => x.Created.Year == year && x.Created.Month == month);
}
```

may be, you should consider support different timezones, summertime or not, something like this as well

Comment: return _DbContext.Carts.Where(x => x.Created.Month >= DateTime.UtcNow.Month && x.Created.Year >= DateTime.UtcNow.Year).Count();  How about this?

Comment: yes, if you only want to have the count of the current month, but without ">"
but that doesn't matter if you haven' entries in the feature or you want to include them

Comment: Yes, total number of orders only from the current month. Thank you

Comment: then remove the ">" if you have data in future

Answer (score 0):

My chief complaint with Nobody's answer is that it manipulates table data, which generally kills the db's ability to use indexes

Consider instead working out the date range and querying it instead:

```
var n = DateTime.Now;
var f = new DateTime(n.Year, n.Month, 1);
var t = new DateTime(n.Year, n.Month + 1, 1);

_dbContext.Carts.Count(c => c.CreatedDate >= f && c.CreatedDate < t);
```